# Robot doesn't move mouse in Java on Chromebook

Tags: java, mouse, awtrobot

Why doesn't the below code work for moving the mouse on a Chromebook?

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class MoveMouse {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
      Thread.sleep(1000); // Add a 1-second delay
   }
}
```

No compile errors, and the program does sleep for a second. However, the mouse doesn't move.

Comment: The code works for me, although the 1 second sleep does nothing perceptible, nor should it.

Comment: Do you run this inside of a VM by any chance?

Comment: I did not run inside of a VM.

Comment: There was a pop-up that asked something like "Allow Java to control your computer" or something of the like, but it disappeared before I was able to select Yes. The pop-up no longer appears every time I run the program.

Comment: @thetypist, _"... it disappeared before I was able to select Yes"_.  It sounds like you accidentally declined the request.

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't recall clicking there, but any idea on how to bring it back? I also tried the same code on ChromeOS (in addition to Mac OS X) and it didn't work there either.

Comment: Was able to fix it on Mac. Was, as you suggested, me having declined the request. Updating OP to it not working on Chromebook only.